# How to solve the following statistic/probability question?

Tags: probability, statistics

**How many ways can 6 books be arranged on a shelf if one of the books is a dictionary and it must be on the end?**

So for this, I know that this is a dependent event but after this I don't know what to do at all?

I know that there are 6 events that needs to happen but how can i know that dictionary will be at the end. There is 1/6 chance that out of the 6 book one is a dictionary. This is all I got from this question, How do i solve this?

Comment: Well, say the dictionary is the one on the left.  Can you now count the ways to arrange the other $5$?  What if the dictionary is on the right?

Answer (score 0):

I assume by **the** end you mean there is only one end. In that case after putting the dictionary at the end, the remaining books may be arranged in $5! = 120$ ways which gives the answer.

Comment: Something's missing here. There are only $6! = 720$ ways to arrange 6 books on a shelf _without_ 'dictionary on a (the) end' restrictions.

Comment: 840? How can that be? It's less than 6! that is the number of permutation of 6 books without your constraint...

Comment: @MATHASKER Are you sure you haven’t misread the answer key? As BruceET pointed out, this is more ways than there are to arrange the books with *no* restrictions. The answer should be 240.

Comment: I'm sorry for that i misread the answer, its 240 but i still don't understand how it was 240 though

Comment: Task 1: Put the dictionary on one end (2 ways). Task 2: Arrange the remaining 5 books in the remaining 5 positions. (120 ways). Multiply. (Did you read Comment from @lulu?)

Comment: you can fix the dictionary at the left or at the right end. In either case there are 120 ways to arrange the remaining books. 240 in total..

Comment: I still don't understand it

Comment: The number of ways of arranging 5 books on a shelf is $5! = 5\times 4 \times 3 \times 2 \times 1$, since you have $5$ choices for the slot of the first book, then $4$ remaining choices for the slot of the second book and so on. The number of arrangements follows from the multiplication principle.

Comment: Yes I understood the 5 factorial, what i don't understand is why u added 120+120 to get 240

Comment: You must first put the dictionary at either end in two possible ways. Then you must arrange the 5 books in 120 ways in each of the two cases giving rise to distinct arrangements i.e 240 in total.